# How to get only those rows that has related data on second table

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables

```
orders table
$table->hasMany("products");
products table
$has->hasOne("product");
and product table
```

Now if i delete the value from product table and want to get those orders's products which has product row. How can i get that?
I used

```
Orders::whereHas('products', function($query){
     return $query->has('product');
})->get();
```

But it is not working.

Comment: It doesn't return results? You could check the executed SQL by Eloquent to see what is the problem: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/display-all-sql-executed-in-eloquent

Comment: It returns all value and showing the product=null. But i don't want to get those rows whose product is null

Comment: I'm not quite understanding, but you want to know which orders had the product you deleted?